# How to access single value property of a collection in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a variable passed though my controller in my view :
 name is **$others**

and when I do a foreach and print it like

```
 @foreach($others as $other)
   {{ $other }}
 @endforeach
```

the output is :

```
[{"employeeID":"9125123981003","email":"admin@gaincafe.com","fullName":"Pranshu Jain"}]     [{"employeeID":"45755757577","email":"yoyo@pranshu.com","fullName":"Pranshu Jain"}]
```

What I want is to access single properties from these ? Are they collections ?

I tried like this

```
  @foreach($others as $other)
    {{ $other->email }}
  @endforeach
```

Here is how I get this `$others` filled :

```
 public function show($id)
   {
    $this->data['leave_application'] = Attendance::find($id);
    $date_applied_on =  $this->data['leave_application']->date;
    $emp_id =  $this->data['leave_application']->employeeID;
    $other_on_leave = Attendance::where('date', '=', $date_applied_on)->get();
    $employees_on_leave = [];

    foreach($other_on_leave as $others) {
        if($emp_id != $others->employeeID) {
           $emptyarray = Employee::where('employeeID', '=', $others->employeeID)->get(array('employeeID','email','fullName'));

           $employees_on_leave[] = $emptyarray;
        }
    }


    $this->data['others'] = $employees_on_leave;
    return view('admin.leave_applications.show', $this->data);
}
```

But it does not work. Kindly help and guide a little bit. I am familiar with array and objects. I used to do well with them. but this seems little complicated.

If i do dd($others) then i get

```
                array:2 [▼
              0 => Collection {#344 ▼
                #items: array:1 [▼
                  0 => Employee {#345 ▼
                    #guarded: array:1 [▼
                      0 => "id"
                    ]
                    #hidden: array:1 [▼
                      0 => "password"
                    ]
                    #connection: null
                    #table: null
                    #primaryKey: "id"
                    #perPage: 15
                    +incrementing: true
                    +timestamps: true
                    #attributes: array:3 [▶]
                    #original: array:3 [▶]
                    #relations: []
                    #visible: []
                    #appends: []
                    #fillable: []
                    #dates: []
                    #dateFormat: null
                    #casts: []
                    #touches: []
                    #observables: []
                    #with: []
                    #morphClass: null
                    +exists: true
                    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
                  }
                ]
              }
              1 => Collection {#346 ▼
                #items: array:1 [▼
                  0 => Employee {#347 ▼
                    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
                    #hidden: array:1 [▶]
                    #connection: null
                    #table: null
                    #primaryKey: "id"
                    #perPage: 15
                    +incrementing: true
                    +timestamps: true
                    #attributes: array:3 [▶]
                    #original: array:3 [▶]
                    #relations: []
                    #visible: []
                    #appends: []
                    #fillable: []
                    #dates: []
                    #dateFormat: null
                    #casts: []
                    #touches: []
                    #observables: []
                    #with: []
                    #morphClass: null
                    +exists: true
                    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
```

Comment: What is the type of **$others**, is it a collection? a `dd($others)` in your controller can tell you.

Comment: And please write your controller function which returns this view.

Comment: @MustafaEhsan Please check

Comment: There is a typo: `{{ $othe->email; }}` should be `{{ $other->email }}` (also without `;`)

Comment: @Adrenaxus typo was not in code, here in writing it came, now see i had done this also removed ; but still not printing out anything.

Comment: At this point We need a `dd($others)` like Mustafa said.

Comment: Please give a screenshot of this **dd's**: `dd($this->data['others'])`

Comment: @MustafaEhsan kindly check now

Comment: @adrenaxus  check now please

Answer (score 0):

Try `first()` instead of `get()` here:

```
$emptyarray = Employee::where('employeeID', '=', $others->employeeID)->first(array('employeeID','email','fullName'));
```

If you still wanted to use `get()`, then do as follow:

```
foreach($other_on_leave as $others) {
    if($emp_id != $others->employeeID) {
        $emptyarray = Employee::where('employeeID', '=', $others->employeeID)->get(array('employeeID','email','fullName'));

        foreach($emptyarray as $arr){
            $employees_on_leave[] = $arr;
        }
    }
}
```

And change this line also, so the view can understand what to loop through:

```
return view('admin.leave_applications.show', ['others' => $this->data['others', 'leave_application' => $this->data['leave_application']]);
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I need to fetch all the results, will using first() do this for me ?

Comment: Isn't the **emplyeeId** unique in **employees** table?

Comment: Updated my question for using with `get()` also. Try now.